# Relative figure size in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, screen, figure

Pretty much it -- is there any way to do it platform-, respectively, backend-independently? In MATLAB, say, it's not a problem, whereas `matplotlib` doesn't even seem to support different units but inches.

Comment: What do you mean by “relative figure size”.  Relative to what?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Relative to the screen size

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dpi of your screen you can convert inches to pixels. But it will work only for screens with the same dpi. Otherwise you have to work with the backend to get the correct size and position of the figure canvas on the screen in pixels